# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied with FFMPEG

Tags: python, python-2.7, ffmpeg

I have just started using Python and am looking at using python to read mp3 files. I tried to use ffmpeg to read the mp3 file, however, i kept getting error of permission denied.

Appreciate if you could advise me on how to resolve this error!

Thank you!

```
$ cd '/Users/jingyi/Downloads/' && '/usr/bin/pythonw'  '/Users/jingyi/Downloads/sound detection.py'  && echo Exit status: $? && exit 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jingyi/Downloads/sound detection.py", line 14, in <module>
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

---

```
    FFMPEG_BIN = '/Users/jingyi/Downloads/ffmpeg'
    #INPUT_Sound = '/Users/jingyi/Downloads/Snore.mp3'

    import subprocess as sp

    command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
            '-i', '/Users/jingyi/Downloads/Snore.mp3',
            '-f', 's16le',
            '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le',
            '-ar', '44100', # ouput will have 44100 Hz
            '-ac', '2', # stereo (set to '1' for mono)
            '-']
    pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: It looks like you downloaded `ffmpeg` from somewhere... Did you check if it has the execute bit set?

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for the answer! yes, i didn't use ffmpeg.exe at first. now it works. :)

Comment: With the execute bit I referred to the executable permission of unix-like systems, not the `.exe` extensions of MS systems. But if I hit the nail nonetheless...

Comment: @rodrigo what do you mean by checking if it has the execute bit? I'm on a Mac and downloaded 'ffmpgeg.osx' from the web because it wasn't in the folder where it was supposed to be when I installed ffmpeg via Homebrew. But now I also get the "Permission Denied" error when trying to use ffmpeg. I think your hint above might be useful for my problem, but I don't understand your hint :D

Comment: having this issue now, how did you solve it?